# SpecRun keeps active in Project, even after uninstall

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, specflow, specrun

I've got an issue with, I believe, SpecRun. First of all, some background information:

I started a brand new Test Project in Visual Studio 2012. I then installed some NuGet packages: SpecFlow, Selenium.WebDriver, Coypu and SpecRun.NUnit. After I created my first testcode and I wanted to run the tests I saw that my tests where showing up double in the Test Explorer. One of the occurences displays '[testname]' as I am used to see in Text Explorer. The other one on the other hand displays '[testname] in [projectname][foldername][featurename]. A whole lot of more information I don't want. Therefore I wanted to uninstall SpecRun and turn back to the NUnit Test Adapter I am used to using for this. Here it began to get messy for me. I tried to uninstall via the Package manager console. PMC said it was removed, SpecRun was removed from my project, but it was still showing as installed in the 'Manage Nuget Packages' window of Visual Studio.

My current situation is that I have two almost the same projects with the same setup. The old one is working as it should, the new one is working, but shows all my tests double as stated above. The only difference is that my new project has SpecRun somewhere in it where I can't remove it. Therefore I'm thinking that SpecRun is somehow creating this problems. Cleaning solution, rebuilding solution, retrying to remove SpecRun, it all didn't help.

To clarify, the problems I keep experiencing:
1. Tests show op twice in the Test Explorer, one as '[testname]', the other one as '[testname] in [projectname][foldername][featurename];
2. It seems that I can't remove SpecRun from Visual Studio 2012. I can remove (/hide) it from my solution, but it keeps showing up in Visual Studio and I can't remove it completely.

[EDIT] One extra pointer that SpecRun is still wanting to do something is that there still is a SpecRun Evaluation test in my TestExplorer that I can't get rid of!

---

**[SOLVED]**
Because I didn't had a solution to this problem yet, I've learned to live with it and worked around it. When James posted an answer, I looked into the subject again, trying to see if the answer James gave could solve the problem. But what I saw was that all the 'duplicate tests' that I couldn't get rid of where already gone and SpecRun was also gone from VS2012. Even the 'SpecRun Evaluation test' was gone in my TestExplorer. This without doing anything I hadn't done before (restarting VS2012, cleaning the solution, rebuilding the solution etc etc). So unfortunatelly I can't tell what solved the problem, but the problem IS solved.

Answer (score 2):

There should be two SpecRun entries in your App.config:

```
<unitTestProvider name="SpecRun" />
<plugins>
  <add name="SpecRun" />
</plugins>
```

and two references to SpecRun in your project references (SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin and TechTalk.SpecRun)

1. Change the unitTestProvider back to MsTest or NUnit
2. Remove the SpecRun plugin
3. Remove both references
4. Regenerate your feature files (right click and select Run Custom Tool)
5. Clean and build your project

That seems to do the job for me at least.

Once all references to SpecRun have been removed then that fact that NuGet is a bit confused doesn't really matter, but if you want to fix it try removing the corresponding `<package>` entry from the packages.config file.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. If this is the answer to solve the problem, I don't know (see the edit above for the explanation why). So I can't mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: You can regenerate all of the feature files in a project by right-clicking the project in Solution Explorer and selecting "Regenerate Feature Files."

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem in Visual Studio 2013.
Just disable Specflow extension for visual studio, restart Visual Studio, and then enable the extension, restart Visual Studio again. Then everything will be alright.